# How can I populate the vim "Insert mode completion" dialog with the shell output?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

```
    [Full code at the end of message]
```

I am trying to write a plugin for vim in which I am calling a ruby script. The function will not be part of the `CTRL-P` autocompletion. I just need to invoke a popup window with options.

The script is passed the method and its previous word. For example `Array.fill` or `some_variable.new` will pass in the whole string while `some_var.some_word.new` would pass `some_word.new`. The plugin will find the arguments of the method and append them to the text in Vim. When there are more than one possibilities it will invoke a popup window for the user to choose.

Everything works well and can get the result pasted in line using:

```
    call setline(line('.'), getline('.') . shell_output)
```

but in the case of multiple possibilities I would like to use a popup dialog that the user can choose what to insert. I tried this:

```
    call complete(col('.'), [shell_output])
```

now vim complains that I am not calling it from insert mode. But I need to call it from normal mode to get the previous word passed in…!!

```
    inoremap <TAB> <esc>"*yiW:call TestDio(@*)<CR>

    function! TestDio(string)
         let result = a:string
         let shell_output = system("ruby SCAutoComplete.rb " . result)
         call complete(col('.'), [shell_output])
    endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to leave insert mode to capture the previous word; you can use `getline()` and `col()` for that. See the example at `:help E839` for how to do that, or use this:

```
let l:startCol = searchpos('\k*\%#', 'bn', line('.'))[1]
if l:startCol == 0
    let l:startCol = col('.')
endif
    let l:base = strpart(getline('.'), l:startCol - 1, (col('.') - l:startCol))
```

Also note that invoking an external Ruby script for each completion is costly. You'll get better performance if you use the built-in Ruby interface (`:help if_ruby`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I decided to use an external scrip in order for the auto-completion to work without the need to compile vim with Ruby. I want to contribute it as part of an open source project and have it always work out of the box. Will check your answer in the following days and return with feedback.

Comment: Had a look but I still don't seem to get what I need.The `completefunc` seems to be too specific to auto-completion which is not exactly what I am trying to achieve. SorryI did not supply enough info in the original post. I submitted an edit and would be grateful if you could have another look.

Comment: If you trigger you kind of completion from insert mode, both `completefunc` and `call complete()` are fine; in fact, they're mostly equivalent. Vim doesn't have auto-completion (only through plugins); the triggering is always manual.